# Making a screen recording of my programming work

Tags: windows, visual-studio, ide, recording

I saw a cool [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y71lli8MS8s) of someone coding a NES emulator. If you watch it, you see that there are no pauses, no hesitations, .. He gives a bit of information on [how this is done](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/jutut/kuvat/programming_examples/nesemu1/FAQ.txt) on his site. The idea is based on tool-assisted videogame speedruns.

Does anyone know tools that can be used to create a similar effect in a modern IDE, like visual studio? Normal video capture programs like CamStudio don't cut it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You'll want to capture in high definition so the text is readable.
  There's nothing worse than a programming tutorial on YouTube where
  you can't read what the guy is typing.
- You'll also want to be able to cut out parts of the recording where there is nothing going on. Hesitations and pauses for thoughts for example.
- It might be a good idea to switch to a low screen resolution (1024x768 perhaps) and run the IDE in a fullscreen mode so that there is no unneccessary clutter in the video and the code is easy to see.

Take a look at that list SQLGuru created for a video capture program which makes the cut.

Comment: This does not actually answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to locate a list of 17 potential apps that could do the trick for you.

check them out here: http://www.freetech4teachers.com/2012/09/17-free-tools-for-creating-screen.html

Comment: As far as I understand regular screen capture software is out of question.

Comment: for what reason?? Many years ago, I did quite a few "demonstrations" using video capture software.